# React, axios, useEffect Returning CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I making CORS request in my react app which is allowed from the server.

When I am making an API call from UseEffect with [] its retuning CROS error but when calling the same API on button click its working fine or with setTimeOut inside useEffect its working fine.

I am not able understand why.

```
function getData(){
  axios.post('/cors_enabled_api_URL',body).then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}


export default function DashBoard(){      
    const {data,setData} = useState(null)
    useEffect(()=>{           
      getData();          // API is not working and returning CORS
    },[])
    return (                
         <h1>DashBoard</h1>
        <button onClick={getData}>Test</button> // API call is Working
    )
}
```

Comment: Two questions... 1) What **exactly** is the error? 2) What is `body`? It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere

Comment: I cannot reproduce any such problem ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-leaf-6jln9c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Phil Answer to #1: In network tab its shows only CORS and in axios just network error. Additionally I feel there is some configuration issue on server or API as I discovered continuous call to Api return CORS but when called after certain time interval it works fine. Will post the my findings here once resolved

Comment: What do you mean by _"only CORS"_? What **exactly** is the error message?

Answer (score -2):

Try adding async to your getData function :

```
async function getData(){
  axios.post('/cors_enabled_api_URL',body).then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}


export default function DashBoard(){      
    const {data,setData} = useState(null)
    useEffect(()=>{           
      getData();          // API is not working and returning CORS
    },[])
    return (                
         <h1>DashBoard</h1>
        <button onClick={getData}>Test</button> // API call is Working
    )
}
```